# Mapped type/using a TS variable for a multiple fields?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, type-variables

So, I would simplify a little bit.
I work with Cognito, and I have the list of possibble attributes, I'll shorten it to:

```
export type CognitoUserAttributes = {
  email?: string;
  name?: string;
  email_verified?: string | boolean;
  address?: Record<string, unknown>;
};
```

and I receive them in such a format:

```
[
{Name: 'email_verified', Value: 'true'},
{Name: 'name', Value: 'John'},
{Name: 'email', Value: 'e@mail.io'}
]
```

How could I create a type, which will give me strict typing of key/value pairs?

Variables doesn't work in syntax like this:

```
export type CognitoUserAttributesResponse = {
  Name: keyof CognitoUserAttributes;
  Value: CognitoUserAttributes[keyof CognitoUserAttributes];
};
```

And this type doesn't do the work, since every key could be every possible value.